# Enforce initialization of Spring Bean which's reference is not explicitly used

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to enforce the initialization of a Spring Bean in cases that the reference of the bean is never explicitly used or even requested in the ApplicationContext?

```
<bean class="foo.bar.FooBar>
  <property name="fooBar" ref="foo.bar.reference"/>
</bean>
```

This bean is meant to do things inside, get's properties passed by IoC but it is never used by any other bean which implies that the it's reference is nowhere else configured.

My problem is, that this bean seems not to be initialized because of that.

I tried `<bean .. lazy-init="false"/>` but this did not do the trick.

How can ensure the bean is going to be initialized?

Since I cannot modify the application context, I would need a way doing it just in the XML configuration.

Comment: `lazy-init` is false by default, and that should make sure that a bean is initialized when the `ApplicationContext` is created. How are you checking that the bean isn't initialized?

Comment: you don't need to reference a bean or request it in ApplicationContext to intialize it. Your problem may be originating from somewhere else, not the config file. Please post your client code that loads the context and the code that uses this bean

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not useful. Can you please post the code in question as @Pat says.

Comment: First of all... How do you *seem* to know the bean is not initialized?

Comment: @Bart I just put a debugging break point in the constructor of the class I would like to have constructed and see it is not be called.

Comment: @Pat I do not have control of the source code where the ApplicationContext is created, I just can configure beans in the XML configuration.

Comment: @Hannes post your full xml config. And also elaborate on how are you verifying that your bean is not initialized? What makes you think so?

Comment: @Pat http://pastebin.com/sVkRT2sf

Comment: Are you sure your XML is loaded?

Comment: @Bart Yes, all other configured bean objects in the XML are constructed if their reference is explicit injected to another bean.

Comment: Beware, at least under Netbeans, I remarked that Spring seems to deactivate all breakpoint during intial context loading. So a break not being called is not a way to know that a bean was not initialized ! The only bullet proof way is logging a message.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I use IDEA and with other beans it works perfectly. But to be completely certain if the constructor is called I will add good old `System.out.println("************ ");` ;-)

Comment: @Hannes I guess, something is wrong with the way you are retrieving your bean from Spring. Ur config looks fine, there is no problem there. As I said earlier, we would need 2 pieces of info: 1) Your analysis approach that makes you think that the bean is not instantiated. 2) Full code of `ActionRegisterExpert` that needs to be instantiated.

Comment: @Pat I DO NOT retrieve the bean from spring anywhere. I only want to construct the bean and everything runs INSIDE the bean, so no other object interacts ever with a reference of this object; it only get references of other beans injected by the means of Dependency Injection.

At the moment the implementation is pretty straight forward:

`public class ActionRegisterExpert {
   public ActionRegisterExpert() {
      System.out.println("*****************************");
   }
}`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you could try to use the singleton=true property for that bean - in non-singleton mode, the bean would be instatiated only if requested by the application.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html
(see 3.2.5)

Edit: Can you add some logging to ctor to see if it's called? If not, could you add an init-method and log something there?

Comment: adding singleton property will not help solving the problem if the bean is not instantiated. `singleton=true` only ensures that a new instance is not created every time the bean is requested. It still doesn't explain why the bean wouldn't be instantiated at all.